# postgresql challenge: how to select sum of one column having another column like 'ab%'

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
fips   value   scc     param
 1      1      123     CO
 1      1.1    124     CO
 1      1.2    125     notCO
 2      1.3    122     CO
 2      1.4    142     CO
```

I would like to select the sum of value where scc starts with `12` and `param="CO"` and have them grouped by `fips`.  SCC is unique per fips (as in multiple fips might have same scc)

I would like these results:

```
fips   sum  
 1     2.1  
 2     1.3
```

I really hope that makes sense.

The query I'm currently using is:

```
SELECT
   fips
 , sum(value)
FROM
   table
WHERE
   param='CO'
GROUP BY
   fips
 , param
HAVING
   scc LIKE '12%'
```

but I have to have column scc in group by or aggregate, grrr.

If I include scc in group by, I get:

```
fips     sum    param
1        1       CO
1        1.1     CO
2        1.3     CO
2        1.4     CO
```

which is not summed at all. That's not what I want.

I'm attempting to simplify this. I actually have a bunch of other columns I hope shouldn't interfere (I could be way wrong), but I hope the design idea is there.  If anyone has any suggestions, I really would be incredibly grateful.

If anyone has any questions that might help them help me, I'd love to hear it.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the condition in `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`.

Comment: Ha, beautiful.  Shows how little I know about sql.

Thanks so very much.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should filter SSC in the where clause, not the having clause:

```
select fips, sum(value)
from YourTable
where param = 'CO'
and ssc like '12%'
group by fips
```